# Get notified when a bounty is provided for question which you (tried to) answer(ed)

Tags: feature-request, bounties, notifications

I found out (by chance) that a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987480/drawing-a-rectangle-using-a-move-gesture/13987758#13987758) for which I provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13987758/246263) got a bounty (due to an upvote I found about it). I thought I answered the question fully and thoroughly and now it seems it is not the case (which is totally acceptable by me).

So, I was wondering whether it would be possible to get some sort a notification for bounties that are given on questions one participated in (by providing an answer)? So people who provided answer(s) are able to update their answers to comply with the bounty reason(s).

As far as I could find out, these notification are currently not possible.

Comment: Meh, this has happened to me; I got a couple of upvotes and the bounty in the end as the OP didn't get a better answer...

Comment: Gah, some other, crappy (less informative and wrong) answer got the bounty... I guess the OP forgot about the bounty?!

Answer (score -3):

I think we need to continue to rely on the OPs' communication skills.

We all apparently agree (see community response to other questions concerning OP feedback, acknowledgment, acceptance rates and up votes) that OPs as a group:

- have read the FAQ,
- always upvote and accept answers when appropriate and
- always acknowledge each answer appropriately.

If they take no action then no action is warranted.  You should assume that those OPs will do the right thing and communicate any issues they may have with your answer.  In this way your requirement will be satisfied and no change to SO is required,

So we don't need this feature at all and the dev team can spend more time on support for  Spring bonnets.

Comment: In this case 'our' agreement, on what the OP has done, does not seem to be correct... But in general, I agree. Especially when an OP offer bounties!

Comment: Just to clarify, I was repeating the party line. Notifications, reminders, etc. that have been proposed to counteract the inability of many PO's to up vote, accept or otherwise acknowledge the effort that went into answering their questions can't seem to get any traction with the powers that be. I happen to have very low expectations with regards to PO's and believe that we should do what we can to offset their ignorance of how SO is supposed to work.  I also have been beaten up for that stand, so now I just reguritate the party line.